Images embedded in TinyMCE email are not read correctly in some email clients (Gmail, Yahoo)
The problem is that TinyMCE emails (sent via PHPMailer) with embedded images are not read correctly in some web email clients. Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail and others.
It is interesting that the same emails coming via Gmail but read in Outlook work fine.
I can only conclude that there is something in the web clients that is not interpreting this correctly.
Sending email to Gmail from Outlook works fine with embedded images.
I am using the following code that came directly from TinyMCE docs:
  file_picker_callback: (cb, value, meta) => {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

    input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      const file = e.target.files[0];

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
      
        const id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
        const blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        const base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        const blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
      });
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });

    input.click();
    },    
    

So, what is in TinyMCE that causes this. I've been researching for days and can't find anything on this.
